# Externally Jar is not connecting to SQL in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven

I'm working on project.while deployment jar in netbeans working properly.
but if I'll copy dependant jars and resources with main Jar.
It gives me error class not found exception while connecting SQL.

Please advice for which files needs to carry while deployment and resolve this issue

Comment: "*while connecting SQL*" does not make sense. `SQL` is a query language. You don't "connect" to it. This is like writing "while connecting Java". Please show us your code and the ***exact*** error message that you get.

Comment: Connectivity Code : Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;user=sa;password=abcd1234;database=abc");



error message : - Class not found exception, Com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

using DSNLess Connection

Comment: "if I'll copy dependant jars and resources with main Jar" where are you coping?

Comment: Now I want to deploy in another machine.So for testing purpose I'm coping necessary content in another folder in same machine

Answer (score 0):

It has to be in classpath beside copying. You didn't mention anything about classpath. Pleasr check the same.

Something like %CLASSPATH%:

Comment: lib,src,target,nbactions,pom which content needs to copy

Comment: Why -1? Care to give the reason?

Comment: maybe other people didn't like your answer

Comment: %CLASSPATH% doesnt exist in windows, java-classpathes are given via the -cp option or looked up automatically

Comment: Can you please more elaborate. deployment time which files needs to carry and where to keep

Comment: @specializt Really? I use it all the time.

Comment: @user3172930 Whta I want to say is that copying is not enough, wont do the trick. You need to set classpath and include all your required jars.

Comment: yes, and if you use it all the time you're using an unset variable.

Answer (score 0):

Gotta answer guy
done below changes in POM.xml

```
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

<executions>
  <execution>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>single</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
  <descriptorRefs>
    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
  </descriptorRefs>
  <archive>
    <manifest>
        <mainClass>com.connect.sql_connection.Connection</mainClass>
    </manifest>
  </archive>
</configuration>
```